# Should I extend the element or create decorators to achieve consistent styling of common UI elements?

Tags: php, forms, oop, zend-framework, decorator

This is definitely a philosophical point but I'm hoping there are clear advantages one way or the other (to settle a debate).

I'm working in Zend Framework 1.12 (PHP). We have a submit button called "start over" which starts over the whole processes. On each form, the button looks the same, is styled the same, and performs the same function. But it's annoying to have to write out all of its properties every time we want to put it in the form.

Should I extend the Submit object and call it StartOver or just make a new decorator and apply it to a submit button each time?

Comment: It the definition of a decorator, how cant you see you using it in this case?

Comment: My thinking is if you create a decorator, it only makes sense to use it on the submit element. But if you extend the submit element, then you can later add more functionality to start over using different states. You're handcuffed if you use a decorator in this way.